# Toggling Animation of UIImageView using UIButton created at runtime

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I'm new to objective C and am attempting to toggle an animation of a UIImageView from one set location on screen to another set location on screen using a UIButton & UIImageView created at runtime. When I press the UIButton, I'd like the UIImageView to animate from one location to another and the UIButton's setBackgroundImage to toggle to another imageNamed: state.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// UIImageView - Roof Panel Creation
roofPanel = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 400, 400, 400)];
[roofPanel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"roof-panel.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:roofPanel];

// UIButton - Panel Lift Button Creation
panelLiftButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(722, 300, 70, 50)];
[panelLiftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panel-lift-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:panelLiftButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to objective C, You will enjoy coding with this great language...

You have to set an image for UIControlStateSelected to UIButton then add target(an IBAction  of a UIButton) as i have shown in below code...

Be sure that images of UIControlStateSelected and UIControlStateNormal must be different.

```
    panelLiftButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(722, 300, 70, 50)];
    [panelLiftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panel-lift-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [panelLiftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panel-lift-button_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [panelLiftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:panelLiftButton];
```

Then make a function like.....

```
-(IBAction)toggleImage:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    btn.selected = ! btn.selected;
    if (btn.selected)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [roofPanel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];//here you can set your desired frame.
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [roofPanel setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 400, 400, 400)];//here you can set your original frame.
        }];

    }

}
```

Enjoy coding with Objective C.